# Coffescript getting executed on all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have a function in my coffeescript "students.coffee":

```
$(document).ready ->
   ...
```

The problem is that this is getting loaded on all pages loads. Is there any way I can restrict this function to run only on the view for a particular action of a specific controller?

Or Is there a way I can explicitly call this method from the specific view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend you to read the [Asset Pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to understand it better.

By default, in `application.js` there's a directive `require_tree` that will load all js files that are in the same folder and sub-folders of the `application.js` file.

That means, that all controller's JS created automatically by Rails generators are going to be added to the compressed `application.js` file and then be executed on every page, since `application.js` is declared on the top of you layout (`application.html.erb`).

If you want specific controller's asset, take a look a [this part](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets) of the Asse Pipeline documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of "require_tree" and I added <%= javascript_include_tag params[:students] %> to my view but the coffeescript does not execute now

Comment: Read carefully the links I sent you. If you pay attention to your request `params[:students]` doesn't exist. You should really put `params[:controller]`. In every Rails request, rails makes it available a controller params so you know what's the current controller. In your case, This controller will be `students`, so Rails will replace the `params[:controller]` by `students` and the html will include the proper javascript. Once again **I highly recommend you to read the docs**

Answer (score 0):

First remove `students` it from your `application.js` manifest file. I'm assuming you don't have `//= require_tree .`. Or that will load everything.

In your specific view where you want to load this file, you can write like this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'students', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: My "application.js" file does not have students and it does have "//= require_tree"